# qtwebengine fails to compile. cant find EGL/egl.h in yocto

Tags: opengl, qt5, yocto, egl

using Yocto Krogoth to build a distro for atom x64 with opengl support. bitbake will build fine without qtwebengine added but adding it causes the error:

> fatal error: EGL/egl.h: No such file or directory

my conf/local.conf i have added:

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " opengl x11 "
IMAGE_INSTALL = "qtbase qtwebengine \
x11-common mesa-gl \
"

CORE_IMAGE_BASE_INSTALL += "mesa-megadriver"
CORE_IMAGE_BASE_INSTALL += "libegl-gallium"
CORE_IMAGE_BASE_INSTALL += "libegl-mesa"
CORE_IMAGE_BASE_INSTALL += "libgbm"
CORE_IMAGE_BASE_INSTALL += "libgbm-gallium"
CORE_IMAGE_BASE_INSTALL += "mesa-driver-pipe-swrast"
CORE_IMAGE_BASE_INSTALL += "mesa-driver-pipe-vmwgfx"
CORE_IMAGE_BASE_INSTALL += "mesa-driver-pipe-i915"
CORE_IMAGE_BASE_INSTALL += "libgles1-mesa"
CORE_IMAGE_BASE_INSTALL += "libgles2-mesa"

PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/libgl  ?= "mesa-gl"
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/mesa  ?= "mesa-gl"
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_mesa-driver-swrast = "mesa-gl"
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/libgles1 = "mesa-gl"
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/libgles2 = "mesa-gl"
```

and if i set virtual/egl to mesa i get

> ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'virtual/egl'
>
> ERROR: mesa PROVIDES virtual/egl but was skipped: PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/libgl set to mesa-gl, not mesa
>
> ERROR: mesa PROVIDES virtual/egl but was skipped: PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/libgl set to mesa-gl, not mesa

and if i set everything to mesa, qtbase will not build because LGL cant be found.

how can i get passed this.

Comment: Did you check all of the configure flags for qtbase? I'm no expert but maybe you can disable PACKAGECONFIG for `gl` and `gles2` if you are setting preferred provider of virtual libgl to mesa...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this patch [from the mesa homepage](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/commit/include?id=a3eb8702fb4de03ca132a66e7e8df1a0b8f85e9a) will help you.

```
diff --git a/include/GL/mesa_glinterop.h b/include/GL/mesa_glinterop.h
index b76bd7e..5c172c6 100644
--- a/include/GL/mesa_glinterop.h
+++ b/include/GL/mesa_glinterop.h
@@ -51,7 +51,7 @@
 #define MESA_GLINTEROP_H

 #include <stddef.h>
-#include <EGL/egl.h>
+#include <stdint.h>

 #ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
@@ -61,6 +61,10 @@ extern "C" {
 typedef struct _XDisplay Display;
 typedef struct __GLXcontextRec *GLXContext;

+/* Forward declarations to avoid inclusion of EGL/egl.h */
+typedef void *EGLDisplay;
+typedef void *EGLContext;
+
 /** Returned error codes. */
 enum {
    MESA_GLINTEROP_SUCCESS = 0,
```

Answer (score 0):

according to
qt5-creator_git.bb:

`REQUIRED_DISTRO_FEATURES ?= "x11 opengl"`

then according to
qtbase_git.bb, **opengl** will depend on **gl** of some kind (gle/gles/gles2):

`PACKAGECONFIG_GL ?= "${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'opengl', 'gl', 'no-opengl', d)}"`

**gl**(**gles2** or something similar) has to be provided by SoC supplier/integrator as it's a graphics hardware accelerator and the driver depends on the actual GPU integrated in the SoC:

qtbase_git.bbappend:

`PACKAGECONFIG_GL = "${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'opengl', 'gles2', '', d)}"`

in case of **Rockchip** SoC - rockchip-common.inc:

`PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/libgles2 ?= "rockchip-libmali"`

in case of **TI** SoC - mesa-pvr.inc:

`PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/libgles2 ?= "mesa-pvr"`

however, qtbase has an option to be built without opengl, but it has to be disabled intentionally:

`PACKAGECONFIG[no-opengl] = "-no-opengl"`